# Make item of list fit in page width

Tags: lists, nesting, fit

The tile just overflows the page, thus its content is lost. How I can make it to break the line and continue below?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

{\large % This what causes the overflow, I guess

\begin{description}
  \item[1) Papadopoulou's SPIE 2014 paper] \hfill \\
  p.4: Voronoi diagram encodes proximity information of the input sites. It can be constructed in
$O(n\log{n})$ time. We have developed the L$\infty$ segment Voronoi diagram in the CGAL environment;10, 25 the code is currently under review for inclusion in the library. Below we list some references.
\begin{description}
  \item[1.1) Implementing the L$\infty$ segment Voronoi diagram in CGAL and applying in VLSI pattern analysis] \hfill \\
  P. Cheilaris, S. K. Dey, M. Gabrani, and E. Papadopoulou, in Proc. 4th International Congress on Mathematical software (ICMS’14), Lecture Notes in Computer Science 8592, 198–205, Springer (2014).
\end{description}

  \item[2) Implement it ourselves] \hfill \\
  Implement an algorithm if a library does not meet our requirements (needs research).
\end{description}
}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get (as one can see "in VLSI pattern analysis" is not shown):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want numbering, you can better use `enumerate`. However, you can also use `enumitem`, ad use

```
\begin{description}[style=unboxed,itemindent=!]
```

if you want to stick with this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

{\large % This what causes the overflow, I guess

\begin{description}
  \item[1) Papadopoulou's SPIE 2014 paper] \hfill \\
  p.4: Voronoi diagram encodes proximity information of the input sites. It can be constructed in
$O(n\log{n})$ time. We have developed the L$\infty$ segment Voronoi diagram in the CGAL environment;10, 25 the code is currently under review for inclusion in the library. Below we list some references.
\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
  \item[1.1) Implementing the L$\infty$ segment Voronoi diagram in CGAL and applying in VLSI pattern analysis] \hfill \\
  P. Cheilaris, S. K. Dey, M. Gabrani, and E. Papadopoulou, in Proc. 4th International Congress on Mathematical software (ICMS’14), Lecture Notes in Computer Science 8592, 198–205, Springer (2014).
\end{description}

  \item[2) Implement it ourselves] \hfill \\
  Implement an algorithm if a library does not meet our requirements (needs research).
\end{description}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On ther other hand, if you use `style=nextline` you can als avoid all those `\hfill\\` after the labels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

{\large % This what causes the overflow, I guess

\begin{description}[style=nextline,itemindent=!]
  \item[1) Papadopoulou's SPIE 2014 paper]
  p.4: Voronoi diagram encodes proximity information of the input sites. It can be constructed in
$O(n\log{n})$ time. We have developed the L$\infty$ segment Voronoi diagram in the CGAL environment;10, 25 the code is currently under review for inclusion in the library. Below we list some references.
\begin{description}[style=nextline,itemindent=!]
  \item[1.1) Implementing the L$\infty$ segment Voronoi diagram in CGAL and applying in VLSI pattern analysis]
  P. Cheilaris, S. K. Dey, M. Gabrani, and E. Papadopoulou, in Proc. 4th International Congress on Mathematical software (ICMS’14), Lecture Notes in Computer Science 8592, 198–205, Springer (2014).
\end{description}

  \item[2) Implement it ourselves]
  Implement an algorithm if a library does not meet our requirements (needs research).
\end{description}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @G.Samaras Did you run my code as it is? I don't get any error.